# Flask werkzeug request.authorization is none but Authorization headers present

Tags: flask, werkzeug

I am POSTing some JSON data and adding an `Authorization` header. However, the request object does not have the correct authorization property. `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` and `headers` both show the proper authorization details.

```
{'authorization': None,
 'cookies': {},
 'environ': {'CONTENT_LENGTH': '81',
             'CONTENT_TYPE': u'application/json',
             'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': 'testkey:',
             'HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH': '81',
             'HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/json',
             'HTTP_HOST': 'test',
             'PATH_INFO': '/v1/test',
             'QUERY_STRING': '',
             'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST',
             'SCRIPT_NAME': '',
             'SERVER_NAME': 'test',
             'SERVER_PORT': '80',
             'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1',
             'flask._preserve_context': False,
             'werkzeug.request': <Request 'http://test/v1/test' [POST]>,
             'wsgi.errors': <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x10d5471e0>,
             'wsgi.input': <_io.BytesIO object at 0x11074c410>,
             'wsgi.multiprocess': False,
             'wsgi.multithread': False,
             'wsgi.run_once': False,
             'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
             'wsgi.version': (1, 0)},
 'headers': EnvironHeaders([('Authorization', testkey:'), ('Host', u'test'), ('Content-Length', u'81'), ('Content-Type', u'application/json')]),
 'shallow': False,
 'url': u'http://test/v1/test',
 'url_rule': <Rule '/v1/test' (POST, OPTIONS) -> testresource>,
 'view_args': {}}
```

Comment: Would you please add in the actual console/web-view error

Comment: @Ondeckshooting - There's no error. Please read the question. The problem is that the authorization property is None, but the proper headers are there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your authorization header `('Authorization', 'testkey:')` needs to be Base64 encoded and include `Basic`.

in python:

```
import base64
base64.b64encode('testkey:') # 'dGVzdGtleTo='
```

in javascript set your header using [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa):

```
'{"Authorization": "Basic ' + btoa('testkey:') + '"}' 
'{"Authorization": "Basic dGVzdGtleTo="}'
```

In your case, the this will result in the header coming in as:

`('Authorization', 'Basic dGVzdGtleTo=')`

Comment: **Needs to be Base64 encoded & include Basic** is crux of it, sample :  `{"Authorization": "Basic  dGVzdGtleTo='"}` otherwise it will show up under `request.environ['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']`

Comment: **Bearer token** can also be sent in the same way but here there no requirement of Base64 encoding though `{"Authorization": "Bearer AbCdEf123456"}`

Answer (score 15):

The `request.authorization` attribute is only set when you have a valid [Basic Authorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) or [Digest Authorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) header; the `Authorization` header has specific formats where the first word in the header value sets the type, and the attribute only handles those two specific types (flagged by the `Basic` or `Digest` type keywords).

From the [`AuthorizationMixin.authorization` attribute documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.9/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.AuthorizationMixin.authorization)

> The *Authorization* object in parsed form.

following that to the [`Authorization` object docs](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.9/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.Authorization):

> Represents an Authorization header sent by the client. You should not create this kind of object yourself but use it when it’s returned by the *parse_authorization_header* function.

which is [documented as](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.9/http/#werkzeug.http.parse_authorization_header):

> Parse an **HTTP basic/digest authorization header** transmitted by the web browser. The return value is either *None* if the header was invalid or not given, otherwise an `Authorization` object.

Bold emphasis mine.

Your header is not such a valid header; it is doesn't have the `Basic` or `Digest` type indicator. If you *did* have such a header the function returns something other than `None`:

```
>>> from werkzeug.http import parse_authorization_header
>>> parse_authorization_header('testkey:')
>>> parse_authorization_header('testkey:') is None
True
>>> parse_authorization_header('Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==')
{'username': 'Aladdin', 'password': 'open sesame'}
>>> result = _
>>> type(result)
<class 'werkzeug.datastructures.Authorization'>
>>> result.username
'Aladdin'
>>> result.password
'open sesame'
```

I used a `Basic` type header there, where the remainder of the header value is a base-64 encoded username and password pair separated by a `:` colon.

If you want to implement your own authentication scheme, just access the header itself and parse it manually.

```
auth = request.headers.get('authorization')
```

Answer (score 10):

When using apache+WSGI, don't forget the `WSGIPassAuthorization On` directive.

Comment: this was very helpful to me, thanks. Out of curiosity, why aren't authorization headers passed by default in apache(or is it wsgi that holds it back) ?

Comment: I was curious too: https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIPassAuthorization.html

Authorisation headers are not passed through by default as doing so could leak information about passwords through to a WSGI application which should not be able to see them when Apache is performing authorisation. If Apache is performing authorisation, a WSGI application can still find out what type of authorisation scheme was used by checking the variable AUTH_TYPE of the WSGI application environment...

Comment: Thank you very much! It saved me a lot of time !!