# Cannot login in flask - always asking username&password

Tags: python, flask

I watched a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VW8qJxy4XcQ) and I saw how easy to login to a webpage in flask. I tried it several times, but when I enter the correct username and password (the saving box comes up for a moment to remember my datas) the little box with the edit texts disappears and it asks them again. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, make_response
import os
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/pass')
def index():
    if request.authorization and request.authorization.username == 'a' and request.authorization.password == 'a':
        return 'logged in'
        #return render_template("index2.html")
    else:
        return make_response('Could not verify!', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate' : 'Basic realm=Login required'})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName 39.234.23.12
                ServerAdmin youemail@email.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

That didn't work, either despite of doing it locally, not on the google cloud virtual instance:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

@app.route("/")
def index():
    if request.authorization and request.authorization.username == 'a' and request.authorization.password == 'a':
        return "success"
    return "nope"
```

Comment: It's very strange. I checked your code it's working. Is anything else in your setup?

Comment: Thanks very much for your quick reply! What else can influence that?

Comment: What version of flask, python are you using? What browser are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7.13  - Flask '0.12.2' - Chrome&Firefox

Comment: How do you run you code? Are you using virtualenv? If yes do you activate it?

Comment: I only used virtualenv when I installed flask on my google cloud virtual instance. __init__.py contains the code above and I just hit python __init__.py and always restart the server when I change something.

Comment: If you use `app.run(debug=True)` then there is no need to restart the server every time you make changes, because it is in the development mode. I still don't understand why code is not working.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27643297/3129414. I would suggest to use form login system as `authorization` is not an object of handling user login to an web application.

Comment: added virtualhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside of using `authorization` you may consider form input. Here is a simple example of creating a simple login system.

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, flash

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'TOO_SECRET_TO_REVEAL'

@app.route('/',methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form.get("username", None)
        password = request.form.get("password", None)
        if username == "shovon" and password=="password":
            flash("Login successful")
        else:
            flash("Wrong username or password")
    return render_template("simple_login.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Then in `templates` folder the `simple_login.html` contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% with flash_messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if flash_messages %}
            <ul>
                {% for message in flash_messages %}
                    <li>
                        {{ message }}
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
    <form action="/" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" /> <br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" /> <br>
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image: login_demo]

To learn more about `flash` view examples in [message flashing](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/flashing/)

Comment: thanks, but I get Method Not Allowed

The method is not allowed for the requested URL. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I have run the code in my local machine and it is running smoothly. Have you configured `flask` correctly in your host? Can you post the full trace back?

Comment: You are right, I tried it locally and it worked perfectly.What do you mean under full trace back? What files do I need to check if flasked is set correctly or not? Thanks very much!

Comment: By traceback I meant the error log. I have not used Google cloud for hosting Flask app. So, I can not help in this regard. Google official documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env

Comment: Your solution worked in a digital ocean droplet, but in a google cloud virtual machine I still get Method Not Allowed. Now I'm rather using the digital ocean droplet, so thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The code should work and looks more like a problem with a browser. Try resetting browser settings to default.

It the problem persists, first check debug log in console and make sure that after login attempt the response status code is 200.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Nov/2017 17:33:10] "GET /pass HTTP/1.1" 200
```

Print out request.authorization before and after checking authorization to see what is passed:

```
def index():
    print(request.authorization)
    if request.authorization and request.authorization.username == 'a' and request.authorization.password == 'a':
        print(request.authorization)
        return 'logged in'
    else:
        return make_response('Could not verify!', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate' : 'Basic realm=Login required'})
```

First print should be None and after authorization second print should be a dictionary with a username and a password:

```
{'username': 'a', 'password': 'a'}
```

After successful authorization, both should return a dictionary with username and password.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Flask. Where can I check the results of the print statements aka where is the debug log? Thanks

Comment: Normally it prints out in the console window, the same window where you start the server.

Comment: I have a google cloud virtual instance and specified this virtualhost. Can something be wrong with this? https://pastebin.com/h2gjX6K5

Comment: If you are running flask with apache, log files are at a location specified in your virtual host (${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log). But since you said you are running it with python init.py, I doubt that you are running it with apache. I strongly suggest that you setup local development environment on your computer and experiment with Google deployment after you learn how flask works.