# flask: When unittesting, request.authorization is always None

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest

I hope that somebody can help me.

I have to write a unit test with unittest of Python in a flask api. I have a login route that works perfectly fine when accessing it through the app with a React frontend but whenever I tried to post from the test, the request.authorization is None... It drives me crazy

I looked all over the internet and tried a lot of different approach but whatever I do, request.authorization is always None when doing a test

Testing :

```
import unittest
import base64

from backend.peace_api import app


class TestLogin(unittest.TestCase):

    # Assert login() with correct authentication
    def test_login(self):
        with app.app_context():
            tester = app.test_client(self)

            auth = 'seo@hotmail.com:password'

            authheader = base64.b64encode(bytes(auth, 'UTF-8'))
            headers = {"HTTP_AUTHORIZATION": "Bearer " + str(authheader), "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"}

            response = tester.post('/api/login/', headers=dict(headers))
            print(response.json)

            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Route :

```
import jwt
import datetime
from flask import Blueprint, request, jsonify
from backend.peace_api import database, secret_key
from backend.peace_api.flat.models.flat import Flat


login_blueprint = Blueprint("login", __name__)


@login_blueprint.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def login():
    auth = request.authorization # This here is always None
    print("Hello World")
    print(request)
    print(request.authorization)
    if auth is None:
        return jsonify({"success": False}, 401)

    email = auth.username
    password = auth.password

    if email is None or email is None or password is None:
        return jsonify({"success": False}, 500)

    mongo_flat = database.flats.find_one({"email": email})
    if mongo_flat is not None:
        flat = Flat(
            mongo_flat["_id"],
            mongo_flat["name"],
            mongo_flat["email"],
            mongo_flat["password"],
            mongo_flat["tasks"],
            mongo_flat["members"],
        )

        if password == flat.password and email == flat.email:
            token = jwt.encode(
                {
                    "id": str(flat.id),
                    "exp": datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30),
                },
                secret_key,
            )
            return jsonify({"token": token.decode("UTF-8")})

        else:
            return jsonify({"success": False}, 401)
    else:
        return jsonify({"success": False}, 401)
```

Printed message :

```
Testing started at 19:15 ...
Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest test_login.TestLogin in [...]\tests
Hello World
<Request 'http://localhost/api/login/' [POST]>
None


Ran 1 test in 0.017s

OK
[{'success': False}, 401]
```

I have honestly no clue what I should do... Thanks for the help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So there are a few issues with your setup which are resulting in the header not being sent or being sent but being malformed.

1. The name of the header is "Authorization", not "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION".
2. The credentials value for the Authorization header needs to be base64 encoded per [the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization).
3. The default [authorization middleware](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.AuthorizationMixin) for Werkzeug only supports [`Basic` auth](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/http/#werkzeug.http.parse_authorization_header), so your `Bearer` token will not work unless you're using an extension that adds `Bearer` support to Werkzeug (without knowing more about your setup it's hard to know what's going on there).

Here's a very simplified Flask App that demonstrates a working test client with a functioning `Authorization` header:

```
import flask
import base64

app = flask.Flask("app")

@app.route("/")
def test():
    print(flask.request.authorization)
    return "Worked"

with app.test_client() as c:
    c.get("/", headers={"Authorization": "Basic {}".format(base64.b64encode(b"useo@hotmail.com:pass").decode("utf8"))})
```

Which prints:

```
{'password': 'pass', 'username': 'seo@hotmail.com'}
<Response streamed [200 OK]>
```

A similar question was asked here:

[Flask werkzeug request.authorization is none but Authorization headers present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630122/flask-werkzeug-request-authorization-is-none-but-authorization-headers-present)